# Drawing Circle In SDL2 Broken

Tags: c++, sdl-2

So I found some code to draw a circle, added it to my project then I tried using it annndddd.. well my program never stops, uses almost all free ram, and does *nothing* (that I can see) here's my whole c++ app there is no other scripts or anything:

```
#include <SDL.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#undef main

//Draw A Circle 
void DrawCircle(SDL_Renderer* renderer, int x, int y, int radius)
{
    int offsetx, offsety, d;

    offsetx = 0;
    offsety = radius;
    d = radius - 1;

    while (offsety >= offsetx) {
        SDL_RenderDrawPoint(renderer, x + offsetx, y + offsety);
        SDL_RenderDrawPoint(renderer, x + offsety, y + offsetx);
        SDL_RenderDrawPoint(renderer, x - offsetx, y + offsety);
        SDL_RenderDrawPoint(renderer, x - offsety, y + offsetx);
        SDL_RenderDrawPoint(renderer, x + offsetx, y - offsety);
        SDL_RenderDrawPoint(renderer, x + offsety, y - offsetx);
        SDL_RenderDrawPoint(renderer, x - offsetx, y - offsety);
        SDL_RenderDrawPoint(renderer, x - offsety, y - offsetx);

        if (d >= 2 * offsetx) {
            d -= 2 * offsetx + 1;
            offsetx += 1;
        }
        else if (d < 2 * (radius - offsety)) {
            d += 2 * offsety - 1;
            offsety -= 1;
        }
        else {
            d += 2 * (offsety - offsetx - 1);
            offsety -= 1;
            offsetx += 1;
        }
    }
}

//Main Loop
int main(int argc, char** args)
{
    //Initialize everything
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);
    //Setting up window and renderer
    SDL_Window* window = SDL_CreateWindow("Hmm", 200, 200, 800, 600, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);
    SDL_Renderer* renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, 0);

    //Draw A Circle, Update the surface, and wait 10 seconds then close the program
    DrawCircle(renderer, 200, 200, 100);
    SDL_UpdateWindowSurface;
    SDL_Delay(10000);

    //Flushes memory and closes program/window
    SDL_DestroyRenderer(renderer);
    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
    SDL_Quit();

    return 0;
}
```

(also feel free to give any recommendations or things that might speed it up)

Comment: `while (x >= y)` This loop obviously never stops, neither `x` nor `y` are ever changing.

Comment: hmm, so how would I go about fixin that?

Comment: found an updated version, though still not workin

Comment: Pixel-wise drawing is unlikely to be fast enough for anything practical. Try using the newly added [`SDL_RenderGeometry`](http://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_RenderGeometry) to render an n-gon with large enough N to look like a circle.

Comment: oh! thanks, I'll check that out

Comment: What's up with that `SDL_UpdateWindowSurface` non-call?

Comment: I may have accidentally left that there or something but I have it fixed in the current code, I can update the question if that is what you would like

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using what HolyBlackCat said, the [SDL_RenderGeometry](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_RenderGeometry) and that seemed to work for what I needed it for.

Comment: Good job getting this solved and thanks for closing out the question with an answer. Though, the timing between the question and answer is a bit curious..... (a mere 219 days `echo $((($(date +%s) - $(date -d "2022-03-08" +%s)) / (3600 * 24)))` ... `:)`

Comment: yeah recently came back to it, I should've come back to it earlier but.. yeahh